# MYSQL query omitting deleted

Tags: mysql, skip

I have a column in my MySQL database for deleted  values are usually 0 or 1. Usually when doing searches I omit the deleted by doing something like "and `deleted` = "0"" but I cant figure out how to get this query below to omit my deleted column. any ideas would be appreciated thanks!

```
$query = "SELECT Status, COUNT(Status) FROM Assets GROUP BY Status"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "". $row['COUNT(Status)'] ." systems ". $row['Status'];
   echo ", ";
}
```

Comment: unless you did an `alter table`, you can't "delete" columns. records, yes. columns, no.

Comment: @MarcB I believe he's saying his column is called "deleted", not that he's actually deleted the column.

Comment: Yes Mansfield that is what I saying. I should have made that a little more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT Status, COUNT(Status) FROM Assets WHERE Assets.deleted = 0 GROUP BY Status";
```

Also, you should use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) rather than mysql (the php mysql library is obsolete).